# how to run gulp tasks from webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, gulp-watch

I have recently updated gulp to 4+ version and then gulp does not start the watch tasks anymore. 
What am i doing wrong? below here is the updated version of code gulp 3+ to gulp 4, I am using gulp.series as per gulp4 docs.

`npm run build` command would have previously copied over the assets folder to 2 other places, its not anymore starting the gulp tasks and gulp watch.

Given myGulpFile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('copytask', function() {
    gulp.src(['assets/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('buildpath/assets'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.resolve(__dirname, '../somepath/assets')));
});
gulp.task('watchtask', gulp.series( function watchtask(){
    gulp.watch('assets/**/*', gulp.series('copytask'));
}));
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('watchtask', function (done) {
    console.log("Gulp started now from webpack!!");
done();
}));
```

Given my package.json for webpack

```
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress -c",
    "watch": "webpack -w --progress -c",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --content-base build",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.production.config.js"
  },
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var something ...;

require('./myGulpFile');

var config = {
...
}

module.exports = config;
```

any help regarding this is much appreciated!

EDIT: To further clarify my question, I want to run gulp by running just one of the webpack commands and automatically start the gulp tasks (this was happening in gulp3+ version using above procedure) but broke after updating to gulp4 version.

Comment: I added an answer, can you try it please ? And tell me what is going on :)

Comment: can you be more specific about your answer, it do not explain me where to do the gulp task execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now, I ended up changing package.json commands and adding `&& gulp -f myGulpFile.js` to the end of the build,dev,deploy commands as below. This will start the gulp tasks right after the webpack commands and you only have to run one initial webpack command `npm run build`

````
 "scripts": {
   "build": "webpack --progress -c && gulp -f myGulpFile.js",
   "watch": "webpack -w --progress -c",
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --content-base build && gulp -f myGulpFile.js",
   "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.production.config.js && gulp -f myGulpFile.js"
 }, ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think now you need to use `gulp` to execute the default gulp and `gulp <name-of-task>` to execute the considered task gulp, for example `gulp copytask`.

Comment: yes `gulp copytask` will and is working when ran by itself, but the question is how to make it run from webpack, i.e. buy running any one webpack cmd by itself like `npm run build` etc